# Unable to access static var from Document Class in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, static, document, root

I have a Document class called "CityModule", and an asset with class "City". Below is the coe for each. For some reason, I am unable to access the static variables of the City class from CityModule:

CityModule.as:

```
package {

  public class CityModule extends MovieClip {

      public function CityModule() {

          var buildings:Array = City.getBuildings(); //gives error

      }
    }
  }
}
```

City.as:

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class City extends MovieClip {

    private static var _buildings:Array = [
        {className:'City.Generic1', type:'generic'},
        {className:'City.Generic2', type:'generic'},
        {className:'City.Generic3', type:'generic'}
    ];

    public function City(){
        //empty
    }

    public static function getBuildings():Array{
        return _buildings;
    }
  }
}
```

Doing this gives me a "Call to a possibly undefined method getBuildings" error. If I instantiate an instance of City, I can see any public/ getters/ setters perfectly fine. But static isn't working...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an import for MovieClip in CityModule.

The following code compiles for me in Flash Develop.

```
//CityModule.as
package  
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    public class CityModule extends MovieClip
    {
        public function CityModule() 
        {
            var buildings:Array = City.getBuildings(); //gives error
        }
    }
}

//City.as
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class City extends MovieClip {

    private static var _buildings:Array = [
        {className:'City.Generic1', type:'generic'},
        {className:'City.Generic2', type:'generic'},
        {className:'City.Generic3', type:'generic'}
    ];

    public function City(){
        //empty
    }

    public static function getBuildings():Array{
        return _buildings;
    }
  }
}


//Main.as
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

            var c:CityModule = new CityModule();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: hmm, i had put that in, but the problem fixed itself somehow? It might be the way I have Flash Builder setup with Flash Pro, i seem to be getting random errors sometimes and then they disappear after tampering around.